# How much should over-the-range microwave stick out?

Tags: kitchens, microwave-oven

I moved into an apartment and want to install an over-the-range microwave. The space above the stove measures 30 in. wide, 11 in. deep, 15 in height. But how far outside of that should a microwave typically stick?

I gather I don't need to vent the microwave to the outside (which is good), but wonder if there's anything else I should think about. I've not done a lot of DIY work in the past.

Comment: By apartment, if you mean the "usual in my area" it's a rental rather than you own it, an OTR microwave is a farly dubious thing, as they approximate "built in" and may upset the owner of the apartment. If you mean a space which you own, go for it.

Comment: Do you mean toward the user? What's the concern?

Comment: @Ecnerwal I mean an "usual in my area" rental, but I can replace the hood without any issues from them. When they redo my apartment, they plan to replace all the appliances, including put their own microwave in. But it'll cost me $200/mo. to get a refurbished apt..

Comment: Is there a power receptacle readily available? If not, you're messing with wiring, which is sketchy, or getting a pro, which is pricey.

Comment: @isherwood Oh, OK. The back of the open space is flat wall, then the cabinets are 11". All the microwaves I see are 15", which means it would extend 4 inches in front of the cabinets. Then, the space is 15" high, but most microwaves seem to be 16 inches tall.

Comment: The biggest issue is power requirements. A vent hood only requires less than 1 amp. Depending upon the age of the apartment and wiring method, it may be connected to a lighting circuit (common).  Microwaves generally are supplied by a dedicated circuit.   I installed one in one of my rentals and ran a new circuit to the panel to provide adequate power.

Comment: "*I gather I don't need to vent the microwave to the outside*"  Why do you think that. Is your current hood vented to the exterior? What kind of stove do you have?

Comment: Most microwave range hoods are shipped with a recirculating fan arrangement. They usually have the option to convert to external venting, but recirculation is the default. So no, it's not required to vent outside in most cases.

Comment: @isherwood I asked for clarification because If the existing hood is vented out then it would be best to vent it out since the duct is already there,  especially if the range is gas. Required and  Best  may not be the same.

Answer (score 5):

As much as the microwave needs it to. They almost always stick out some, both forward and below the side cabinets.

Most upper cabinets are ~12" deep. My microwave comes out another 2-1/2" or so beyond the face of the cabinets (without the handle) and hangs below about 2". The top mounting screws are maybe 10" from the wall, so as long as your cabinet has that depth and is robust enough to support the weight, all good.

Comment: How can I tell if they're strong enough to support the weight?

Comment: Same way you'd tell if a chair was going to collapse if you sat on it. Use some common sense! This isn't rocket surgery. :)

Comment: On a slightly more serious note, @Jeff, use a stud finder to see if they built in any horizontal bracing that you could mount it to. If there is, you should be golden. If not, use the stud finder to find where the studs are and see how they line up with the mounting screws for the microwave. If you've got studs right behind the mounting holes, you're golden! If not, peruse this forum for questions about mounting things to drywall, but consider the weight of the oven _plus_ the (HOT) food you're cooking before you decide to continue with this endeavor.

Comment: There is some concern that the cabinets in an apartment aren't up to the task. It's for that and other reasons I didn't get into that issue. It's out of scope here as the question stands and is a broad topic. Photos or a a clear description would be required for specific advice.